# Could not open ServletContext resource - applicationContext.xml

Tags: spring

I am trying to migrate my java ee application from struts to spring, as a first step I chnaged the tags in my jsp from a certain file to it's spring equivalent

1. Adding Spring taglibs

Struts

```
<html-em:form> ... </html-en:form>
```

to Spring

`<form:form> ... </form:form>` etc..

I kept changing until i received the above error

**No WebApplicationContext found no Context loader listener registered**

I saw a lot of posts mentioning adding a **listener** in

```
web.xml
```

so i added in the following

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
                 org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
            </listener-class>
</listener>
```

Now it is giving me a

**Could not open ServletContext resource** error

after some research online I realised that I need to have a

```
applicationContext.xml
```

In my project. But I do not know where to find this file.

All I have is a

`ApplicationContext-uvo.xml` somewhere in my Javasource

Can anyone guide me as how to solve this error?
**Thanks in advance**

Comment: You're basically asking "How do I use Spring?" You don't "find" this file, you *create* it. A Spring tutorial seems like a really good idea right about now.

Comment: Thanks for the response @DaveNewton, I have searched online for a lot of tutorials, would you suggest a few

Comment: Nope, don't know any, stopped using Spring ~5yrs ago.